# How to copy a nix profile

Tags: nixos, nix

Is it possible to copy a Nix user profile or a configuration to another users or hosts ?

I mean, let's say I installed some package using `nix-env -i`. How can I copy this environment and use it somewhere else ?
Same question for NixOs configuration. I can create a new configuration by modifying `/etc/nixos/configurtion.nix`. But what If I added some package using `nix-env -i`. Can I generate a configuration (or equivalent) corresponding to this new environment ?

Comment: Why the negative vote ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should use `configuration.nix` to have declarative configuration that you can carry around.

To get all installed packages for particular profile run `nix-env -q`.

There is also `nix-copy-closure --help` that you could use to copy `~/.nix-profile` profile.

Answer (score 1):

For nix-env, you can use a file to keep the name of all the packages, something like described here: https://nixos.org/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_manage_software_with_nix-env_like_with_configuration.nix.3F

To have the same exact output, then you also want to do a checkout at a specific commit of nixpkgs.